# IF, ELSE IF, ELSE ou IF IF IF. Quando usar, qual a diferença?

Tags: javascript, if, else, condição

É uma questão bem básica, porém que me intriga bastante. Vejam o código abaixo:

```
var bola = "redonda";
if(bola == "comestivel") return comer();
if(bola == "liquida") return beber();
if(bola == "redonda") chutar();
```

Agora vejam o mesmo com `if`, `else if` e `else`

```
var bola = "redonda";
if(bola == "comestivel") return comer();
else if(bola == "liquida") return beber();
else chutar();
```

Ou seja, o mesmo fim pode ser obtido de ambas as maneiras.

O `else if` e `else` não teriam apenas efeito semântico?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No seu exemplo, não faz mesmo diferença, por dois motivos:

1. Não existem duas condições que possam ser atendidas ao mesmo tempo.
2. Você sempre retorna quando entra em um dos `if`, e os seguintes não executam

Agora considere o seguinte exemplo:

```
var numero = 100;
if(numero <= 100) {
    console.log("menor ou igual a 100");
} else if(numero < 1000) {
    console.log("menor que 1000");
}
```

O `else` não será executado, pois já entrou no `if` (*else* quer dizer "senão"). Blocos de `else` e `else if` só executam se nenhuma das condições anteriores tiver sido atendida. Contraste com isto:

```
var numero = 100;
if(numero <= 100) {
    console.log("menor ou igual a 100");
} 
if(numero < 1000) {
    console.log("menor que 1000");
}
```

Aqui ambos são executados, já que são duas condições independentes e o número `100` atende a ambas.

Answer (score 29):

## Semântica

As linguagens de programação costumam ter construções diferentes para dar efeitos semânticos diferentes. Raramente você precisa de uma construção diferente se não quer este resultado.

## Simplicidade

Você deve tentar sempre usar o mais simples possível. Eu considero que o mais simples é o `if` com bloco simples (só um comando), sem condicionais extras ou contra condicional.

## Como funciona bloco de `if`

Mas há casos em que isto não é possível. Quando você tem uma situação em que um um bloco de ação é excludente em relação ao outro, você precisa utilizar o `else`. Bom, na verdade não precisa. Você pode colocar um segundo `if` em seguida com a condição invertida, mas isto não faz muito sentido, piora a leitura e manutenção.

Isto vale também quando tem uma série de opções mutualmente exclusivas, ou seja, que apenas uma é válida. Você até pode fazer vários `if`s, mas se a decisão está interligada, se é mais lógico que seja feito como uma só operação é melhor escolhê-la.

## O que é melhor

Então sim, no seu exemplo você deve fazer escolher o `else if` principalmente por questão de semântica. Mas isto não é algo bobo que só serve para atender uma regra. Realmente facilita ler e mexer no seu código sem causar problemas no futuro.

Códigos devem ser escritos primariamente para seres humanos lerem. Então é muito útil dar o entendimento correto do que está fazendo ali. [Quando todas as escolhas levam ao mesmo lugar escolha a mais simples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor). Podemos adaptar esta afirmação para o propósito de manutenção: se todas as formas resolvem o problema, escolha a que expressa melhor a sua intenção.

Fazer `if`s separados que estão logicamente ligados passa a ideia errada. O meu entendimento é que seu código está fazendo uma única decisão lógica. Mesmo sendo mais simples usar o `if` simples, não é mais simples ler um código assim.

## Além da questão do `if`

Mas existe um outro problema. Eu não diria que seus dois códigos fazem a mesma coisa. Eles não são equivalentes. Tá, eles até são da maneira como está escrito. Mas ninguém escreve código assim a não ser para exemplificar.

```
var bola = "redonda";
if (bola == "comestivel") return comer();
if (bola == "liquida") return beber();
if (bola == "redonda") chutar();
```

e

```
var bola = "redonda";
if (bola == "comestivel") return comer();
else if (bola == "liquida") return beber();
else if (bola == "redonda") chutar();
```

são equivalentes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Ifs.js).

Em um código real poderia haver um situação que a variável `bola` não vale nenhum destes textos. O seu código executará `chutar()` se o texto for diferente das duas opções iniciais no segundo código, mas não executará no primeiro se a primeira situação for igual. No código acima, ambos farão a mesma coisa.

Observe a resposta do bfavaretto que mostra que pode haver um outro problema quando escolhe a opção de `if`s isolados. No seu exemplo não causa problema, mas quando você pode ter duas condições sendo atendidas e você quer que apenas um bloco seja executado (são mutuamente exclusivos, ou executa um ou outro), separar o `if` dará resultado inesperado, ele poderá executar os dois blocos e não é o que você quer.

## Conclusão

Por isto achar o mais simples é complicado. É comum programadores menos experientes fazerem coisas extremamente complicadas porque não sabem como fazer o simples. Parece um contrassenso mas é o que mais acontece. O mais simples nestes casos é a estrutura que parece mais complicada (não que seja muito).

---

Acho que existe ainda um outro problema no código que não parece tão relevante para a pergunta (mas pode ser) e que estou apenas intuindo já que este não é um código real. No terceiro caso você está executando a função `chutar()` mas não está retornando o resultado desta função. Nas condições anteriores você está retornando o o resultado da função. Pode ser que não tenha resultado algum mesmo. Aí não faria diferença.

Mesmo assim eu ainda colocaria `return chutar()` no final a não ser que tenha um motivo para não por. É uma questão de simetria. Se a intenção é terminar a função ali, diga explicitamente que vai fazer isto. Se a intenção claramente não precisa retornar um valor em nenhum caso, você deveria então tirar todos os `return` para deixar claro que não está retornando um valor. Ou pelo menos chamar a função e só depois usar o `return`.

Por último eu prefiro dar um espaço entre o `if` e o `(` da condição para não confundir com uma função chamada `if`.

Comment: Eu complementaria com:
var bola = "redonda";
if (bola == "comestivel"){
   return comer();
}else if (bola == "liquida"){
   return beber();
}
//nem um nem outro e  não precisamos fazer outras verificações?
return chutar();

Answer (score 16):

As demais respostas já explicam muito bem, mas gostaria de complementar com o seguinte: com frequência existem várias maneiras de se fazer a mesma coisa, sem que exista claramente um "melhor" ou "pior", de modo que cabe a você - pela sua experiência ou pelo seu *feeling* - decidir qual delas usar caso a caso.

Aqui não se pode ter nenhuma instrução após aquela sendo escolhida (sem repetir código):

```
if(bola == "comestivel") return comer();
if(bola == "liquida") return beber();
if(bola == "redonda") return chutar();
return nenhumaDasAnteriores();

qualquerUmaDelas(); // Nunca executará
```

Aqui se pode fazer algo depois que a ação correta foi escolhida (mas retornar um valor é mais "chato"):

```
if(bola == "comestivel") comer();
else if (bola == "liquida") beber();
else if (bola == "redonda") chutar();
else nenhumaDasAnteriores();

qualquerUmaDelas(); // Seja o que for feito, isso será feito depois
```

Aqui se pode fazer a mesma coisa com duas ou mais condições diferentes (ou duas ou mais coisas com a mesma condição):

```
switch(bola) {
    case "redonda":
    case "oval":
        chutar(); // redonda ou oval, chuta
        break;
    case "comestivel":
        comer(); // comestível, só come
        break;
    case "sorvete":
        comer(); // sorvete derretendo, come...
    case "liquida":
        beber(); // ...depois bebe; liquida, só bebe
        break;
    default:
        nenhumaDasAnteriores();
}
```

Aqui se pode alterar as condições dinamicamente:

```
var acoes = {
    comestivel:comer,
    liquida:beber,
    redonda:chutar
}

var fn = acoes[bola] || nenhumaDasAnteriores;
fn();

...

acoes.leve = arremessar;
```

Etc. Para se determinar qual é a "mais simples", ou "mais correta", ou "mais fácil de dar manutenção" (e muito de vez em quando "mais eficiente"), somente pensando no código como um todo - e não somente se concentrando no trecho particular em que se testam as condições.

Answer (score 13):

Há um efeito funcional: em uma estrutura condicional, quando um bloco é executado, os demais são ignorados.

Ou seja, no primeiro exemplo, há três estruturas condicionais, enquanto no segundo, há uma estrutura condicional divida em três blocos. No primeiro exemplo, as três estruturas são executadas; enquanto no segundo, caso uma seja executada, as demais serão ignoradas (sem perder tempo verificando, desnecessariamente, as condições dos argumentos).

Nesse caso, acredito que não haja diferença, porque aparentemente esse código está dentro de uma função, e ao retornar um valor, o resto do código não é executado.

Comment: Então um `if-else if` tem um ganho de performance por ignorar o restante?