# Se o usuário digitar tal número no console fará uma ação

Tags: c#

Como faz para quando o usuário digitar tal número no Console fará uma ação?

Por exemplo:

```
Console.WriteLine("Escreva 1 para acontecer algo, 2 para acontecer outra coisa");
```

No caso não preciso do que vai acontecer pois já tenho código, só estou com a dúvida de como fazer para verificar se o usuário digito 1 ou 2, e dar uma ação para determinado número

```
log.WarnFormat("1 ou 2");
string escreveu = Console.ReadLine();
var numero = 1;
if (numero == 1) cupons();
if (numero == 2) cuponsusuario();
```

Comment: Você pode usar estruturas condicionais... dê uma olhada neste post
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41504/11404

Comment: Okay tentei fazer mas não obtive sucesso, não consigo fazer ele verificar se é 1 ou 2

Comment: certo, coloque o trecho do código que você está obtendo a entrado do usuário e a forma como está fazendo para validar os dados de entrada

Comment: log.WarnFormat("1 ou 2");
                                string escreveu = Console.ReadLine();
                                var numero = 1;
                                if (numero == 1) cupons();
                                if (numero == 2) cuponsusuario();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa ler a entrada usando `Console.ReadLine()`. O `Console.ReadLine` sempre retorna uma `string`. Então, se quiseres fazer alguma comparação numérica terá que converter para inteiro antes.

Por exemplo:

```
Console.WriteLine("Escreva 1 para acontecer algo, 2 para acontecer outra coisa");
var strEntrada = Console.ReadLine();

int input;
if(int.TryParse(strEntrada, out input))
{
    switch(input)
    {
        case 1: 
            FazerAlgo();
            break;
        case 2: 
            FazerOutraCoisa();
            break;
    }            
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Valor inválido");
}
```