# Condicional If sem comparação lógica - Necessito saber o que retorna

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia pessoal, sou novo com JS e gostaria de entender uma coisa. Quando temos uma condicional IF no JS sem uma "Comparação" como ela funciona ? O que ela retorna ? O interpretador de código entra nessa condicional caso ela seja o que ?

Preciso saber o que a condicional IF retorna para assim entrar na condicional.

Vou deixar um exemplo:

`var supportsAudio = !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;` 
`if (supportsAudio){execução}`

Comment: qual é a próxima linha depois do `if (supportsAudio)` ? e por que essa atribuição com a dupla negação `!!`? Isso é a mesma coisa que simplesmente `var supportsAudio = document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;`

Comment: Também pode ser útil: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/315434/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165494/101

Comment: O `!!` transforma a expressão em *booleano* (ver [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29014/112052)), e depois o `if` verifica se esse valor *booleano* é `true`. Complementando, dentro de um `if` pode ter qualquer valor, que ele usa [essas regras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/112052) para determinar se é verdadeiro ou falso

Answer (score 0):

Parece que há um equivoco na maneira que você está interpretando o funcionamento do `if`.

Uma estrutura `if` não precisa receber uma comparação, ela precisa receber uma condição para ser executada, geralmente `true` ou `false`.

Quando você escreve uma comparação dentro da condição do seu `if`, você não está passando a comparação em si como condição, mas sim o resultado da comparação.

Veja o exemplo

```
var i = 10;
if (i == 10) {
    // o resultado da comparação é true, por isso o código é executado

}

var j = 20;
var cond = j == 20; // o resultado da comparação é gerado nessa linha, ele é true
if (cond) {
    // como a condição do if é true, ele será executado
}
```

Então, no seu exemplo, o que está acontecendo é que a sua condição está sendo gerada por meio da dupla negação `!!`.

O operador `!` irá negar o valor retornado do método `document.createElement('audio').canPlayType`, resultado em `true`, ou `false`, adicionando um segundo `!`, você nega o valor anterior. Por que?

Isso pode ser útil quando você está tratando objetos por exemplo. O valor retornado da negação de um objeto é `false`, enquanto a negação de um valor `null` é true.

Então se você negar um objeto duas vezes, seu resultado será `true`, enquanto se você negar um valor `null` duas vezes, o seu resultado será `false`.

Dessa maneira, a sua estrutura `if` só irá ser executada, se o valor que está na variável for um objeto, ou seja, se o valor não for `null`.

Comment: Não precisa excluir a resposta só porque a pergunta está marcada como duplicada. É boa a sua resposta.