# Elaboração de cifra de césar em python

Tags: python, criptografia

Opa galera, sou novo por aqui e no mundo da programação, então toda crítica é bem vinda.
Estou com um problema com essa cifra de cesar que venho tentando fazer.
Poderiam me apontar possíveis erros, e formas de melhorar esse código, adicionando funções.

```
   print ("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-")
print("Criptografia de César")
print(" ")

#recebe a chave de critografia e valida
chave = int(input("digite a chave de criptografia (ate 26)\n"))
while chave > 26 or chave < 0:  
    print(" ")
    chave = input("chave inválida, tente novamente")

base = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

#escolhe o modo
modo = str(input("Deseja encriptar ou descriptar\n"))

#insere e formata o texto
text= str(input("Digite o texto a ser criptografado\n"))
tamanho_txt = len(text)
text = text.lower()


#insere o texto final
cripto =''

char = 0
    #escolhe o modo
if (modo == 'e' or modo == 'encriptar') :

    while char <= tamanho_txt:

            #recebe o word de comparação
        word = text[char]

            #enquanto o word estiver coontido na base de comparação
        for word in base[0:len(base)]:

                #encontra o numero da posição dp word na base
            posicion = base.find(word)

                #soma a chave á posição
            posicion + chave

                # se a posição for maior que a base ira calcular a diferença
            if(posicion > len(base)):
                posicion = posicion - len(base)

        #concatena a o word encontrado           
        cripto = cripto + base[posicion]

        char = char +1

if (modo == 'd' or modo == 'decriptar'):
        # contador do texto
    while char <= tamanho_txt:
            # recebe o word da posição
        word = text[char]
            #condição se o word estiver contido na base
        for word in base[0:len(base)]:
                #encontra a posição
            posicion = base.find(word)
                #subtrai a chave
            posicion - chave
                #condicional se a posição foi menor que 0
            if posicion <= 0:
                    # subtrai o valor absoluto da base para encontrar a posição
                posicion = len(base)- abs(posicion)

        #resultado            
        cripto = cripto + base[posicion]
        char = char + 1      

print("sua mensagem \n" + cripto)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá. Bem, seu código está bem bagunçado. Além disso, possui muitas irregularidades que não podem acontecer ou que são extremamente redundantes.
Posso citar os dois que logo vi ao ler seu código:

- **Dois IFs para mesmos dados:**

Quando estamos tratando duas ou mais possibilidades para um certo dado (no caso aqui é o input do usuário), o ideal é por um `if/elif/else`. Se quiser saber mais sobre a causa, temos [já uma pergunta  e resposta no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41499/if-else-if-else-ou-if-if-if-quando-usar-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a).
Então podemos já substituir o segundo if por um `elif`.

- **Laço for com construção estranha**

O laço for percorre todos os itens de um objeto iterável (strings, tuplas, sets, dicionários e listas), e no seu caso não há necessidade de percorrer usando o `[0:len(base)]`, uma vez que isso é exatamente a mesma coisa que por a própria `base` como argumento do for.

Ou seja, basta renomearmos `for word in base[0:len(base)]:` para `for word in base`.

- **Há uma linha que não faz nada**.

Quando você faz qualquer operação, o Python apenas executa. O resultado você só salva na memória se atribuir numa variável, ou adicionar em algum objeto que pareça um array (como um `dict` ou um `list`). A linha em questão é a

```py
posicion + chave
```

, onde o correto seria

```py
posicion += chave
```

---

De resto, acredito que o erro seja mesmo de lógica. No caso, você poderia explicar o seu algoritmo? Eu realmente não consegui entender bem qual foi sua intenção digitando o que foi digitado. Mas sobre a lógica, posso apontar uns erros:

- Me parece que você não entendeu muito bem o conceito do laço for. Ele não verifica a condição, ele faz aquilo que falei agora pouco: itera cada item de um objeto iterável, no caso da *string*, cada item é um caractere. E ao invés de usar a *base*, você deveria usar o texto do input do usuário.
- O laço `while` nesse caso também é inútil, uma vez que a limitação do tamanho do input já pode ser imposta num laço for, que percorre exatamente todos os caracteres dos dados que o usuário inseriu (`input`).
- Além disso, os dois ifs para caso haja "sobrecarga" (quando a letra for *z* e eu tenha de ir para *a*, ou vice-versa) você apenas aplicou uma lógica incorreta. O correto seria, respectivamente, `if(posicion > len(base)):` e `if posicion < 0:`. Onde o primeiro deve indicar caso seja apenas maior que o comprimento do alfabeto e no segundo apenas se for menor que 0.

---

Corrigindo todos os erros, chegamos ao código final:

```
print ("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-")
print("Criptografia de César")
print(" ")

#recebe a chave de critografia e valida
chave = int(input("digite a chave de criptografia (ate 26)\n"))
while chave > 26 or chave < 0:  
    print(" ")
    chave = input("chave inválida, tente novamente")

base = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

#escolhe o modo
modo = str(input("Deseja encriptar ou descriptar\n"))

#insere e formata o texto
text= input("Digite o texto a ser criptografado\n")
text = text.lower()


#insere o texto final
cripto =''

    #escolhe o modo
if (modo == 'e' or modo == 'encriptar') :
    for word in text:
                #encontra o numero da posição dp word na base
        posicion = base.find(word)

            #soma a chave á posição
        posicion += chave

            # se a posição for maior que a base ira calcular a diferença
        if(posicion > len(base)):
            posicion = posicion - len(base)

    #concatena a o word encontrado           
        cripto = cripto + base[posicion]

elif (modo == 'd' or modo == 'decriptar'):
        # contador do texto
            # recebe o word da posição
            #condição se o word estiver contido na base
    for word in text:
            #encontra a posição
        posicion = base.find(word)
            #subtrai a chave
        posicion -= chave
            #condicional se a posição foi menor que 0
        if posicion < 0:
                # subtrai o valor absoluto da base para encontrar a posição
            posicion = len(base)- abs(posicion)

    #resultado            
        cripto = cripto + base[posicion]

print("sua mensagem \n" + cripto)
```

Comment: +1 resposta bem completa

Comment: cara legal demais, obrigado pelas dicas e prometo trabalhar para melhorar minhas falhas, você abordou todas as duvidas que eu tinha. Como deu pra perceber ainda estou aprendendo o básico, fiz esse código apenas como auto-desafio, e já percebi que o "achar" que é certo e o "certo" são bem diferentes. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O python possui uma função perfeita para a cifra de césar, que é a `str.translate`:

```
def cesar(texto, deslocamento):
    alfabeto = string.ascii_lowercase
    alfabeto_deslocado = alfabeto[deslocamento:] + alfabeto[:deslocamento]
    tabela = string.maketrans(alfabeto, alfabeto_deslocado)
    return texto.translate(tabela)
```

Por exemplo:

```
>>> print(cesar('ola', 10))
yvk
```

para descriptografar é só inverter o sinal do deslocamento:

```
>>> print(cesar('yvk', -10))
ola
```