# Como um "if" funciona internamente?

Tags: if, característica-linguagem, compilação, independente-de-linguagem

O `if` é muito usado na programação, e ele cumpre vários papéis importantes no dia a dia de um programador. O código parece que magicamente é executado se uma expressão  passada no `if` for verdadeira, caso contrário aquele código simplesmente é ignorado.

Mas como que ele funciona **internamente?**

Usem esse código como base (pseudocódigo):

```
var x = 8;
if (x < 4) {
    print("x é menor do que 4!");
} else {
    print("x é maior do que 4!");
}
```

Comment: Esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41504/110782) te ajudaria?

Comment: @LuizAugusto eu estou falando como um if funciona **internamente**, como que a "mágica" acontece

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vamos dizer que não existisse o bloco de comandos, então ficaria mais ou menos assim (sem otimização):

```
var x = 8;
if (x < 4) goto TRUE;
print("x é maior do que 4!");
goto FIM;
:TRUE
print("x é menor do que 4!");
:FIM
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/IfUnderlying.ptg).

imaginando que entenda o conceito de `goto` e *label* que usei em `TRUE`, se não souber cabe pergunta específica.

Mas ainda não explica como o `if` é executado.

Bom, o processador sabe como tomar uma decisão, existe pronto um código que sabe se deve fazer algo ou não deve fazer algo, só isso, ele não analisa a condição. Isto costuma ser chamado de *branch*, ou seja, ele pega um galho ou outro galho. No Intel é a instrução `jz` ( ou `je`, `jne`, ou outras [veja uma lista](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow)).

[image: Trilho de trem com um desvio]

Internamente tem um monte de portas lógicas que executarão um algoritmo para tomar essa decisão, mas basicamente o que ela faz é desviar a execução (muda o registrador `PC` que é o registrador que guarda o endereço da próxima instrução a ser executada) se existir um valor em uma *flag* do registrador ([veja a lista delas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register)).

Essa *flag* do registrador terá um valor de acordo com a última execução de uma instrução anterior possivelmente de comparação (não necessariamente) que tenha alterado uma das *flags* que será verificada. Então a condição é feita de forma separada do `if`. Eu sempre disse que no fundo o que acontece é isto (muitas pessoas não entendem e acham que a condição faz parte do `if`:

```
var x = 8;
var cond = x < 4;
if (cond) goto TRUE;
print("x é maior do que 4!");
goto FIM;    
:TRUE
print("x é menor do que 4!");
:FIM
```

Note que o `if` e o `goto` ainda são uma coisa só, apenas uma instrução causa o desvio condicionalmente (diferente da instrução [`JMP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMP_(x86_instruction)) que causa o desvio incondicionalmente e é o `goto` simples).

Claro que em algumas linguagens isso funciona um pouco diferente até porque rodam em máquinas virtuais, mas em essência é a mesma coisa. O mesmo vale para processadores diferentes.

De fato em C compilaria mais ou menos para isto:

```
.LC0:
        .string "x \303\251 menor do que 4!"
.LC1:
        .string "x \303\251 maior do que 4!"
teste:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 8
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 3
        jg      .L2
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
.L3:
        nop
        leave
        ret
```

[Veja no **Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/QdWfxM).

No caso o `jg` é a instrução que toma a decisão (ela é *jump if flag value is greater*). A instrução `CMP` é que faz a comparação e gera um valor na *flag* [`ZF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_flag).

Em C# seria isto:

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 26 (0x1a)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldc.i4.8
        IL_0001: ldc.i4.4
        IL_0002: bge.s IL_000f

        IL_0004: ldstr "x é menor do que 4!"
        IL_0009: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_000e: ret

        IL_000f: ldstr "x é maior do que 4!"
        IL_0014: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_0019: ret
    } // end of method C::M

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x206b
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

} // end of class C
```

[Veja no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQBEJinANjASQDsYIFsBjCAgWwAdcIaITYBLAeyIBoYQ3cAHwACABgAEwgIwA2SVIB0AYS7IOjANwBYAFDCAzJIBM4peIDeu8dcmHhAFnEBZABQBKC1ZveAblATiAB7iALziABzaOt7ebGDiLsEAPOL2HgDqCGykADJsRBAuAETBAJfizEQcAQAmHOIAjnAQqQCERW5RMTYQuMgtmdkQeQXFZRVQnLX1TS327Z1e1gC+ustAA).

E em Assembly:

```
; Core CLR v4.700.19.46205 (coreclr.dll) on x86.

C..ctor()
    L0000: ret

C.M()
    L0000: mov ecx, [0x10998940]
    L0006: call System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)
    L000b: ret
```

[Veja no SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQBEJinANjASQDsYIFsBjCAgWwAdcIaITYBLAeyIBoYQpkNAD4ABAAwACEQEYAbFOkA6AMJdkHRgG4AsACgRAZikAmCcokBvPRJtSjIgCwSAsgAoAlJeu2fANygIEgAeEgC8EgAcOro+PmxgEq4hADwSDp4A6ghspAAybEQQrgBEIQCXEsxEHIEAJhwSAI5wEGkAhMXu0bG2ELjIrVk5EPmFJeWVUJx1Dc2tDh1d3jYAvnorQA===). Aí você pergunta: onde está a condição? O compilador percebeu que poderia resolver em tempo de compilação e matou o `if` :). Em C se ligar todas otimizações ele fará o mesmo. Algumas linguagens sabem otimizar bem.

Não vou entrar na questão das portas lógicas que fica baixo nível demais, mas é só manipulação de dados existentes no processador (foi colocado lá antes), como já dito antes, a condição gerará um valor em uma das *flags* do processador que não deixa de ser um registrador, e um valor é mudado no `PC` (`IP` para alguns), depois a execução continua no endereço da memória que está marcado nesse registrador.

Por ser algo mais difícil para a maioria se tiver algum ponto não entendido avise, eu posso melhorar a resposta de acordo com a necessidade.

Comment: Você falou nos _branches_  de execução e obviamente me lembrei desta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/4438007

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado agora pode apreciar a foto aqui tb, roubei :D

Answer (score 3):

Um **compilador** converte seu código fonte para código de máquina, no qual é entendível pelo computador. Durante o processo de conversão, o código fonte passa por várias fases do compilador.

Uma dessas fases é  a *fase geradora de código intermediária*, no qual o código intermediário para o seu código fonte é gerado, no qual é otimizado na *fase de otimização de código* para aumentar a eficiência do código no geral, e assim, finalmente ser convertido em código de máquina na *última fase de geração de código*.

Agora para responder sua pergunta.

Um código intermediário é representado usando a *Notação de 3 Endereços*. Um código de 3 endereços é representado da seguinte maneira:

```
Result := Argument_1 operator Argument_2
```

É chamado Código de 3 Endereços porque há 3 referências para o endereço das variáveis.

Por exemplo esse bloco de código (Essa é a resposta que você procura):

```
var x = 8;
if (x < 4) {
    print("x é menor do que 4!")
} else {
    print("x é maior do que 4!");
}
```

Agora a representação do código de 3 Endereços vai ser a seguinte:

```
1) var x = 8;
2) var Result = x < 4;
3) if Result then goto (5)
4) goto (7)
5) print("x é menor do que 4!");
6) goto (8)
7) print("x é maior do que 4!");
8)
```

Sim, o `if` funciona usando `goto`. É assim que isso funciona:

- Ele primeiro verifica se `x < 4` em uma variável usando notação de 3 endereços.
- Se a condição for `true`, o programa vai para a linha 5.
- Se a condição for `false`, ele vai para a próxima linha, na qual manda o programa para a linha 7.
- As linhas 5 e 6 é o bloco de código dentro do `if`. A linha 6 manda o programa para a linha 8, no qual está basicamente saindo do bloco `if-else` e continua processando o resto do código.
- A linha 7 é o pedaço de código no bloco `else`. Como o `else` "está" no fim, ao terminar de executá-lo automaticamente o programa já vai para o código após o bloco `if-else`, então não é necessário um `goto`.

Então é assim que o `if` funciona. `goto` é usado extensivamente pelo compilado através do código. Isso não é limitado ao bloco `if`.

Note que também é possível em alguns lugares que a condição seja executada diretamente no `if`, como `if x < 4 then goto (5)` baseado no exemplo acima.

Comment: Eu tenho a impressão que pra ser mais próximo da linguagem de máquina a instrução 8 deveria ser `nop`, o _no operation_, exceto se tiver alguma comando após a execução da condicional

Comment: O `3AC` é muito importante nos processos de optimização dos código gerados pelo compilador.