# Uso de && e || dentro de While

Tags: c#, .net, loop, while, condição

Tentei realizar o exercício a seguir:
[image: Exercício while]

O que eu não entendo de jeito nenhum, é porque tenho que usar `&&` (e) dentro do while ao invés de `||` (ou). Entendo que o && seria para o caso de que x e y tem que ser diferentes de 0 ao mesmo tempo. E no caso do `||` se um ou outro forem iguais a 0 então o programa fecha.
Não entendi o porquê de usar &&.

Detalhe: tentei usar o `||` e não dá certo

Resolução do exercício:

```
string[] vet = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int x = int.Parse(vet[0]);
        int y = int.Parse(vet[1]);

        while (x != 0 && y != 0) 
        {
            if (x > 0 && y > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("primeiro");
            }
            else if (x < 0 && y > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("segundo");
            }
            else if (x < 0 && y < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("terceiro");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("quarto");
            }                               
            vet = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            x = int.Parse(vet[0]);
            y = int.Parse(vet[1]);
        }
```

Comment: Andressa por favor coloque um exemplo dos dados que voce esta usando de exemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não tem que usar operador algum dentro de `while`. Este comando espera um valor booleano, ou seja, um `false` ou um `true`, só isso.

Talvez por se ensinar errado por aí fique mais difícil de entender. E eu não sei se conseguirei explicar melhor aqui, porque para ver tudo precisa de uma aula completa de lógica, que vai até mais de um capítulo de um livro ou várias horas de um curso. Não se aprende como se fosse uma "dica miojo", ou seja, algo que vê em 3 minutos e já sabe como usar. Para programar precisa ir passo por passo, sem pular nada e de forma lenta.

Não vou pegar na prática que alguém começou inventar há algum e tempo que não é boa de pedir para a pessoas entrar com mais de um dado na mesma linha separado por algum caractere específico. Muita coisa pode dar errado fazendo isso e não é uma boa ideia. Vai no mais seguro que é pedir os dados separadamente.

E já falei sobre a questão da condição do `if`, que é a mesma coisa do `while`, só que um executa zero ou uma vez e o outro volta ao ponto inicial e pode executar zero ou várias vezes. Se quiser pode ver [detalhes técnicos avançados sobre o que é um `if`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420854/101) (não é leitura simples para iniciantes, mas é fundamental para entender melhor essa construção de linguagem).

Eu dei uma [resposta que talvez ajude entender melhor essa dissociação da condição do `if/while` e de uma expressão que resulta em um booleano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165494/101). E [mais uma em outra linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44741/101). E [mais outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/315434/101).

Para entender os operadores, decomponha a expressão fora do `while` ou dos `if`s, até porque não tem diferença quando usa em um lugar ou outro. Se entende o motivo de usar no `if` não tem razão para não entender no `while`, se não consegue entender isso, eu não conseguirei explicar.

A primeira coisa que precisa entender desses operadores é que eles são [*short circuit*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101), ou seja, quando ele já estabelece um resultado que ele sabe que não pode mudar mais, ele não tenta ver o resto.

Assim, se você usar um `||` e a primeira expressão antes dele der verdadeira, ele não tentará fazer a segunda porque não importa qual seja o resultada sela, o resultado final da expressão toda que é aplicada o `||` já é garantido que será `true`, afinal, basta um dos lados ser `true` que tudo será `true`.

Com o `&&` acontece o oposto, se der `false` na primeira expressão não tenta a segunda expressão porque não tem mais como não dar `false`, afinal neste operador ambos precisam ser `true` para o todo dar `true`, e um deles já dando `false` é impossível dar outro resultado.

E o que deseja que é as duas expressões sejam verdadeiras, se uma delas for falsa você não quer que seja feito nada.

O exercício é ruim porque fala em valor nulo, coisa que não faz sentido em entrada numérica. Eu vou entender que ele quis dizer que uma das entradas deve ser 0. Podem ser as duas. Note que esta é a condição para sair do laço e encerrar. Qual é a necessidade para **continuar** executando? Esse é o segredo.

Pensou? Já sabe? Vou responder.

Então para entrar ou continuar no `while` é o oposto, precisa que nenhuma das entradas seja 0. Precisa que **ambas** sejam **diferentes** de 0. E qual é o operador que exige que ambos sejam verdadeiros para dar verdadeiro? É o `&&`, não é o `||` que exige apenas uma.

Se você usar o `||`:

- com 0 e 1: `x` é diferente de 0? Não, então dá `false`, e aí tem de ver a outra expressão que é: `y` é diferente de 0? Sim, então dá `true`, portanto tudo dá `true` e continua no `while` porque é assim que este comando funciona.
- com 1 e 0: `x` é diferente de 0? Sim, então dá `true`, e aí não tem de ver a outra expressão, portanto tudo dá `true` e continua no `while` porque é assim que este comando funciona.

Não é o que deseja.

Se quer usar o `||` dá, mas aí a expressão seria outra porque quer que continue o laço:

```
!(x == 0 || y == 0)
```

- com 0 e 1: `x` é igual a 0? Sim, então dá `true`, e aí não tem de ver a outra expressão, portanto tudo dá `true`, aplica o `!` que inverte o valor, e então fica `false` e sai do `while` porque é assim que este comando funciona.
- com 1 e 0: `x` é igual a 0? Não, então dá `false`, e aí tem de ver a outra expressão que é: `y` é igual a 0? Sim, então dá `true`, portanto tudo dá `true`, aplica o `!` que inverte o valor, e então fica `false` e sai do `while` porque é assim que este comando funciona.

Mas tem uma forma mais óbvia de escrever isso que é fazer o que o exercício pede de forma direta, ou seja, interpretar o texto e executar exatamente o que diz e não tentar inverter a lógica, que cria toda a complicação e faz o código ser pior.

Resolvendo os problemas, deixando o código menos redundante, e fazendo o que o exercício pede de forma simples e direta, eu faria assim:

```
using static System.Console;

while (true) {
    if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var x)) return;
    if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var y)) return;
    if (z == 0 || y == 0) break;
    if (x > 0 && y > 0) WriteLine("primeiro");
    else if (x < 0 && y > 0) WriteLine("segundo");
    else if (x < 0 && y < 0) WriteLine("terceiro");
    else WriteLine("quarto");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/eSOl32). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BEfhPk). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Quadrant.cs).

Dá para usar um `&&` e ter um `if` apenas na entrada de dados.

Na verdade, poderia ser mais amigável se fizesse isto e deixaria o operador de lado:

```
using static System.Console;

while (true) {
    if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var x)) return;
    if (x == 0) break;
    if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var y)) return;
    if (y == 0) break;
    if (x > 0 && y > 0) WriteLine("primeiro");
    else if (x < 0 && y > 0) WriteLine("segundo");
    else if (x < 0 && y < 0) WriteLine("terceiro");
    else WriteLine("quarto");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bsBqRV). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TRJQON). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Quadrant2.cs).

Considerei o encerramento da aplicação sem erro se o digitado é inválido. Eu mesmo [respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) sobre esse tipo de exercício diversas vezes, procure outros exemplos aqui.

Comment: Maniero sua resposta foi simplesmente espetacular. Estou ingressando agora no mundo da programação e estou fazendo um curso de C# pela Udemy e esse exercício realmente me deixou confusa. Ainda não cheguei na parte dos booleanos mas já vi alguma coisa num curso de lógica de programação. 
De qualquer forma vc me deu uma aula aqui e agora posso continuar exercitando com mais cuidado e atenção! Muito obrigada e vou procurar mais conteúdos seus!!